# Using re.sub but keeping some letters from search pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have a search pattern

```
re.sub(r'[^eyioae]ill[eyioae]', 'y ', val, re.I)
```

but I want to keep any letter that won't fit the condition `[^eyioae]`.
So, if to process 'ville', an output will be 'vy'.
How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zero width positive look-behind:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[^eyioae])ill[eyioae]', 'y', 'ville', re.I)
'vy'
```